# dropout ratio ideal value?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I know what a dropout ratio is and how it helps but i have two questions:

1. i don't know how it works i know that much it switches off some of the neuron but how it helps in increasing accuracy.
2. I have seen sometimes people apply very large dropout ratio sometimes very low so it confuses me is there any ideal value for dropout ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no common value of dropout ratio which you can use everywhere it depends on your model and a number of hit and trials. Its value should not be too high otherwise your model will not be trained properly and it should not be too low as the model will still be overfitted.

Now to your first question when we turn off some of the neuron it prevents over fitting which occurs when when the model learns too much from your sample data.

Comment: so we should use a dropout ratio of about 0.5 in most cases

Comment: Yeah most of times I have made a model I chose such values but do some hit and trials

Comment: "so we should use a dropout ratio of about 0.5 in most cases"—No, you don't get to pick that for free. Tune this hyper-parameter just like you tune any other.